# Static casting to incorrect type

Tags: c++

I Realised that this method is particularly useful when debugging code when I Don't want to change/build an an external library.

Am yet to burn my hands with this or is this safe atleast for debugging?

http://ideone.com/i9jBN8

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(int lx):x(lx){};
protected:
    int x;
};

class B : public A
{
public: 

    void print(){std::cout << x << endl;}
};

int main() {
    A *a = new A(22);
    B *b = static_cast<B*>(a);
    b->print();
}
```

Edit: what if use I use reinterpret_cast instead of static_cast and make sure that B doesn't have any virtual methods, wouldn't the memory of A and B match and it wont be an UB right?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: > Am yet to burn my hands with this or is this safe atleast for debugging?

Comment: The call of `b->print()` is formally undefined behaviour, since `b` does not actually point to a `B`.   The only way to be sure it is safe for debugging is to test, with your particular tool chain.   You would be better off providing some capabilities in class `A` that can be used for debugging purposes.

Comment: The result of this cast is simply *undefined*. `b` is whatever the compiler chooses it to be. Don't let get yourself get fooled by the typical C++ issues of *works most of the time*  and *works for me*. We've all been there ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior, but since it's quite simple you can probably convince yourself whether it'll work on your implementation by examining the intermediate assembly code or the disassembled binary.

Chances are good that it will work in practice, especially for simple classes. The main fear with these kinds of "it looks like it ought to work even though it's UB" situations, is that the optimizer will make some very clever deduction based on an assumption that it's entitled to make, but which isn't true of your UB code. So turning off all optimization gives you a better chance of seeing (dis)assembly that (a) does what you intended and (b) you can make sense of.

For this example at least, you can access the value of `x` for debugging purposes without undefined behavior and without modifying the class `A`, by taking a copy:

```
class B : public A
{
public: 
    B(const A&a) : A(a) {}

    void print(){std::cout << x << endl;}
};

int main() {
    A *a = new A(22);
    static_cast<B>(*a).print();
}
```

Comment: what if use I use reinterpret_cast instead of static_cast and make sure that B doesn't have any virtual methods, wouldn't the data of A and B match and it wont be an UB right?

Comment: @tejas: still UB. Just about the only thing you can portably do with a pointer that's been `reinterpret_cast` is to cast it back to the original type.

Comment: Btw, since `A` and `B` are both standard-layout classes since C++11, it *is* guaranteed that `x` is "in the same place" in both of them, that is to say that the offset of `x` from the `A*` is the same as the offset of `x` from the `B*`. So you're right that the data matches. But I'm calling this UB because AFAIK this *still* isn't enough to provide defined behaviour per the standard. The strict aliasing rules in [basic.lval] don't permit you to refer to an object using a derived class of its dynamic type, even though they have the same layout.

Answer (score 4):

No this is not safe, in fact it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (see bullet 2 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)).  If you want to cast a base pointer to a derived pointer you should use [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) as that will return a `nullptr` if the conversion is invalid.

Comment: It doesn't matter if `print()` does anything that requires `B`. That just makes the issue apparent. This "nifty" way of monkey patching is undefined already after the static_cast.

Comment: Could you link to a reference page that says it is undefined behavior?